# Is there a svg to pdf_tex converter without Inkscape?

Tags: pdftex, svg

Is there a `.svg` to `.pdf_tex` converter without Inkscape?

Comment: @percusse I don't want to use any external LaTeX packages. I want to convert .svg to .pdf_tex on computer, and include its output into LaTeX source code.

Comment: Is no a sufficient answer? You can also use an online service to convert your SVG to PDF (or EPS) for inclusion in your document.

Comment: @Werner Thanks. I'd converted my SVG to PDF, and included it on LaTeX.